# What is the simplest way to get IP address of a domain?

Tags: dns

We're developing an embedded application, running on a standalone GPRS connected device (no operating system there). We are trying to get an IP address of domain name. I think that we should use some public DNS service, like Google DNS (`8.8.8.8`). The question is - what is the simplest request we should send to `8.8.8.8:53` in order to receive IP address of our domain?

Again, we can't use `libresolve` or any other similar libraries. We will make a simple TCP connection to port `53` of Google DNS, and will format our request ourselves.

I tried to understand [RFC1053](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) myself, but failed. Too many words :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a DNS expert in any way, but I thought that DNS generally use UDP rather than TCP?

Either way, here's a link to a [page](http://www.netfor2.com/dns.htm) that describes the communication using less words that might be easier to understand than the RFC itself.

Also, even if you can't use the libresolve library itself, can't you look at an open source version of that library and use the code from one of those (assuming that the license is compatible with your work). Here's one from [Apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-129.13/libresolv.c) that I found via google.

Comment: Answers that basically just link to an external page are not ideal since links may die. Would you care to summarize the method described in the page you link to?